# When I am adding script in Lightning Salesforce App I have got this error "Content Security Policy"

Tags: community, lightning-apps

When I am adding script  in Lightning Salesforce App. I have got this error given below

### Error :

Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js 
("script-src https://bappi--davidtest.lightning.force.com chrome-extension: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' ).

Please provide your suggestion.

Comment: Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js ("script-src https://staffhub--davidtest.lightning.force.com chrome-extension: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/").

Answer (score 1):

Better option is download https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js this js file upload into static resource

and use `ltng:require` for load static resource. once static resource loaded acll your init function from `afterScriptsLoaded`

```
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/resourceName" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.init}" />
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: I have already done. But I have got same error.

Comment: whats the error?